# Why does adding UILabel in subView makes it pixelated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I'm making a message that is shown when the tableView is empty and I've added a label in my subView and it appears to be pixelated. But when I add something in my tableView and delete it, then the message shown (UILabel) is perfectly fine. Can't figure out why.

Adding the label in my `self.tableView.backgroundView = emptyLabel` solves it but I want to add two labels so I add one in `subView` that makes it pixelated.

Here is my code:

```
class ReminderTableViewController: UITableViewController
{

@IBOutlet var myTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UIView!
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: self)

}
 public func buttonImageForEmptyStateView() -> UIImage? {
    return UIImage.init(named: "Exclamation Mark Filled-100-2")
}



override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
     self.reloadEmptyState(forTableView: self.tableView)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    if list.count==0{
        let emptyLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
        let emptyLabel2=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 20.0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))


        self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel2)
        self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel)

        let emptyImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Quote Right Filled-100 (3)"))
        emptyImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
        self.view.addSubview(emptyImage)
        emptyImage.alpha=0.1
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            emptyImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            emptyImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            emptyImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
            emptyImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90)
            ])


        emptyLabel.text = "no present reminders"
        emptyLabel.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
        emptyLabel.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

        emptyLabel2.text = "you add by going back to the homescreen"
        emptyLabel2.textColor=UIColor.gray
        emptyLabel2.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11)
        emptyLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center


        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none

        return 0
    }
    else{
         return (list.count)
    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text=list[indexPath.row]
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.89, green:0.89, blue:0.89, alpha:0.7)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor=UIColor.black
    cell.textLabel?.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 16)
    return (cell)
}





override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is there a transform on the label's parent (or parent's parent &c)?

Comment: No, no transform used.

Comment: have you tried testing on iphone instead of simulator ?

Comment: @Alshcompiler  Yes I have. It has the same result.

Comment: where do you call this code

Comment: in my `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{}`

Comment: @S.Verma could you show me whole implementation of this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberOfRowsInSection` is call multiple times, so there is not good place to add subview because every time this function is call another UILabel's instance add to view hierarchy.

Remove adding labels in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Add class variables:

```
var emptyLabel: UILabel!
var emptyLabel2: UILabel!
var emptyImage: UIImageView!
```

then add the function

```
 func createEmptyLabels() {
    emptyLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
    emptyLabel2=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 20.0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))


    self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel2)
    self.view.addSubview(emptyLabel)

    emptyImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Quote Right Filled-100 (3)"))
    emptyImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(emptyImage)
    emptyImage.alpha=0.1
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        emptyImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        emptyImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
        emptyImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90),
        emptyImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90)
        ])


    emptyLabel.text = "no present reminders"
    emptyLabel.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
    emptyLabel.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 18)
    emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    emptyLabel2.text = "you add by going back to the homescreen"
    emptyLabel2.textColor=UIColor.gray
    emptyLabel2.font=UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11)
    emptyLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center

    emptyLabel.isHidden = true
    emptyLabel2.isHidden = true
    emptyImage.isHidden = true
}
```

call this function in `viewDidLoad`

and in `numberOfRowsInSection`:

```
let hideEmptyViews = (list.count != 0)
emptyLabel.isHidden = hideEmptyViews
emptyLabel2.isHidden = hideEmptyViews
emptyImage.isHidden = hideEmptyViews
```

Comment: it shows the labels and the imageView when the table has some entries. It plays the counter role. I want it to be shown when the TableView is empty

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be `let hideEmptyViews = (list.count != 0)` I have edited my answer.

Comment: yes it works, any idea how I can change the order of appearance of labels and UIImages. I want my my image to be beneath of my labels.

Comment: Use `UIStackView`

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the label in `numberOfRowsInSection`. The problem is that this method is called many times. So you are adding many copies of the label, piled on top of one another, and this makes the label look funny.

Comment: how do I remove this pile and makes the label not look funny.

Comment: If you've already added the label and it's still there, don't add it again.

Comment: And nowhere do I see you _removing_ the label once added, or _checking_ to see whether it has been added. So it just keeps getting added again and again, as I said. You have merely confirmed what I already answered.